# How does this piece of TSQL work?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, errors

Why the following batch doesn't work as expected?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #test1;

IF 1 = 1
    SELECT *
    INTO #test1
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE database_id <= 5;

ELSE
    SELECT *
    INTO #test1
    FROM sys.databases;


SELECT *
FROM #test1;
```

When I run it, I got:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
> There is already an object named '#test1' in the database.

And I have to change the code like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##test1;

IF 1 = 1
    EXEC ('
    SELECT *
    INTO ##test1
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE database_id <= 5;
    '    );

ELSE
    EXEC ('
    SELECT *
    INTO ##test1
    FROM sys.databases;');


SELECT *
FROM ##test1;
```

This works as expected. The aforementioned error seems like a parsing error, which I'm not sure. Could anyone help to explain what's happening here?

Comment: Why does this need a temp table anyway? Just do a straight `SELECT`

Comment: [Does SELECT INTO Reserve the #Object Name in TempDB Prior to Runtime?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128862/does-select-into-reserve-the-object-name-in-tempdb-prior-to-runtime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is generated at parse time, so before the batch is even executed.  And it only happens when the `INTO` target is a temporary table (either local or global).  It does not occur when the target is a regular table.

One way to work around this issue is to use dynamic SQL, as you have shown.  And as you have also discovered, the method does not work with local temporary tables, which may not always be fine.

You can also create the target table beforehand and switch to populating it with `INSERT...SELECT` instead of `SELECT...INTO`, [as suggested by Aleksey Vitsko](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/317593).  One situation I can see this might not be convenient is when the query returns multiple calculated columns, as you would first have to determine the data types correctly in order to accommodate the output data without causing overflow, precision loss, conversion errors or other such things.

To address both issues (keep using local temporary tables, avoid having to define target columns explicitly), you could try rewriting the script like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #test1;

/* the query from the "if true" branch */
SELECT
  *
INTO
  #test1
FROM
  sys.databases
WHERE
  database_id <= 5
  AND ...  /* your IF condition should go here */
;

IF NOT (...)  /* the negated version of your IF condition goes here;
                 make sure to account for possible "unknowns" */
  /* the "else" branch query */
  INSERT INTO
    #test1
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    sys.databases
;

SELECT * FROM #test1;
```

The first query will run and create the target table.  If the `IF` condition is true, the table will also be populated, otherwise it will be empty.  The next statement will populate the created table in case the condition was not true.

Answer (score 3):

> Why the following batch doesn't work as expected?

There are some guru's here that can probably explain this much better, but what happens in your first variant is that the table is declared twice. Each time you do "SELECT INTO" table is declared, so you get this parsing error

If you declare table explicitly first, and then insert into it, you won't get error (number of columns was reduced to avoid much typing):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #test1;

create table #test1 (ID int)

IF 1 = 1
    insert INTO #test1 (ID)
    select database_id FROM sys.databases
    WHERE database_id <= 5;

ELSE
    insert INTO #test1 (ID)
    select database_id FROM sys.databases

SELECT *
FROM #test1;
```

Dynamic SQL can be used to bypass errors and resolve things that otherwise could not be resolved

Answer (score 2):

The workaround I prefer is creating the temp table first, then doing an `INSERT INTO` in your branched code like so:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #SomeTable;
CREATE TABLE #SomeTable (Field1 INT, Field2 VARCHAR(100));

IF 1 = 1
    INSERT INTO #SomeTable
    SELECT Field1, Field2
    FROM dbo.SomeOtherTable
    WHERE Field3 <= 5;

ELSE
    INSERT INTO #SomeTable
    SELECT Field1, Field2
    FROM dbo.SomeOtherTable;
```

When you want to match the temp table structure to the source of the inserted data, then you can use a trick with `TOP 0` like this to have it create the structure for you:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #test1;
SELECT TOP 0 *
INTO #test1
FROM sys.databases;

IF 1 = 1
    INSERT INTO #test1
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE database_id <= 5;

ELSE
    INSERT INTO #test1
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.databases;
```

Another way to re-write your code with the same logical outcome would be:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #test1;
SELECT *
INTO #test1
FROM sys.databases;

IF 1 = 1
    DELETE FROM #test1
    WHERE database_id > 5
```

Of course this results in extra work in the database to execute though.

---

Note I normally tend to not use `SELECT *` in production code, because it is an anti-pattern for many reasons. But one case where it *may* be ok is in your test use case above where you want to ensure you're binding the structure of the temp table to exactly the same structure as the underlying table. But further on in the code, I would recommend being explicit in which columns you utilize or return at the end of the query.